# Is FlutterFire safe from attacking?

Tags: firebase, flutter, security

What I mean is from attacking from hacker like DOS.

I start intern at startup company, my job is to develop a food delivery application.
Right now, I'm using firebase with flutterfire package to authenticate and send data. I allow authentication by Anonymously(<-this method is where I concern, can someone DOS by create new UID rapidly?), Facebook, Gmail and AppleID.

I also need to send sensitive informations like credit card and address to store on server. Is there any security risks that I should concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase protects its services against abuse where reasonable possible. For example, a DoS by creating anonymous user accounts in rapid succession, will quickly lead to a block on that IP address.

Firebase can be used to build secure applications, but (just like any technology) it can also be used in improperly secured applications. Covering the difference between those two cases is as complex a topic as how to build the application itself though, so quite a bit too broad to reasonably write in a single answer here on Stack Overflow.